# Sql Server, How do I make a front end?

Tags: usability, gui-design, tools

extremely nooby question. I've worked with access for a while but now I'm trying to dive into SQL. I've looked around and I can't seem to figure out how you make a front end for the damn thing. I need it to be web browser based and accessible over the internet. Are there any Rapid development tools for building a quick web based gui for sql server? Something kinda like access (where I can actually use menus and guis instead of just pure code?).

also, if anyone could recommend a decent book on sql that would be great.

Comment: What flavor of SQL, what Internet servers, what is your goal beside learning?

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for UX.stackexchange. You might find some help with this Microsoft article though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I think that this is maybe a question for UX, but is TOO broad.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting I would suggest you could use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) to learn Apache, PHP, and mySQL locally.

The WAMP and MAMP web sites are full of information to get you started.

W#Schools has a good introduction [tutorial to MySQL & PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) and a quick Google search will yield dozens of others.